# Why still get data from localstorage after removed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, local-storage

I define my localstorage like this:

```
export default new class LocalStorage {
  setItem(key, data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}();
```

and my RestrictionRoute like this:

```
const localStorageData = LocalStorage.getItem("root");    
export const RestrictionRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
      console.log(localStorageData);
      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={props =>
            localStorageData && localStorageData.token ? (
              <Redirect to="/" />
            ) : (
              <Component {...props} />
            )
          }
        />
      );
    };
```

My logout action:

```
export function logOut() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(changeLoadingStatusTo(true));
    LocalStorage.removeItem("root");
    dispatch(changeLoadingStatusTo(false));
    dispatch(push("/login"));
  };
}
```

When I click logout in header, my logout action is triggered, the data also removed in local storage, and in RestrictionRoute, I check localstorage again by `console.log(localStorageData)`, then the data still exist. This make me confused.

Comment: `localStorageData` is a copy of–not a reference to–the localstorage.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: what @str said, you need to bring the `const localStorageData = LocalStorage.getItem("root"); ` inside of your `RestrictionRoute` so that it gets called every time it renders.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, ya it worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try check directly "LocalStorage.getItem("root") instead of printing the value stored in the variable, since localStorage is the copy of the data present where you initialized your class.